# OpenTok Android SDK 2.0, setPublishVideo(false) does not free the Camera. Any workarounds known?

Tags: android, opentok

I'm trying to take a picture while there's an ongoing OpenTok video conference in an Android application. I use OpenTok SDK 2.0 for Android.

I tried to use publisher.setPublishVideo(false) to temporarily free the Camera so that the default Camera Activity can be used to take a picture. But looks like OpenTok does not free the Camera hardware.

As a workaround I tried using session.unpublish(publisher), which frees the Camera (and it also cuts the audio stream which is not desirable for me) but once I'm done with taking a picture, this time the a/v is not restored with session.publish(publisher).

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late response, but figured this may help for anyone who comes across the same issue.

My solution was to destroy capturer prior to starting intent to take picture

```
mPublisher.setPublishVideo(false);
BaseVideoCapturer bvc = mPublisher.getCapturer();
if(bvc != null){
    bvc.destroy();
}
//intent to start picture capture (Ex. ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

When you resume after taking the picture, you will need to initialize again

```
BaseVideoCapturer bvc = mPublisher.getCapturer();
if(bvc != null){
    if(bvc.isCaptureStarted() == false){
        bvc.init();
        bvc.startCapture();
        mPublisher.setPublishVideo(true);
    }           
}
```

Comment: Didn't actually try if this works (not working on the Android project anymore). But thanks for the detailed answer. So, I'll accept this.

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer using your detail comment

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried `publisher.onPause()` and `publisher.onResume()`, this work for me.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never tried it, but using Android 2.0 beta 2, you might be able to use PublisherKit to accomplish something like that. There are methods like `setRenderer(BaseVideoRenderer renderer)` and `setCapturer(BaseVideoCapturer capturer)` that might allow you to programmatically free the camera on `setPublishVideo( false )`

Good luck!